# python code problem

Tags: python, google-app-engine

i have this code:

```
class Check(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()

    be = "SELECT * FROM Benutzer ORDER BY date "
    c = db.GqlQuery(be)

    for x in c:
      if x.benutzer == user:
        s=1
        break
      else:
        s=2
    if s is 0:
      self.redirect('/')
```

to check whether the user is registered or not.
but it gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 511, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "/Users/zainab_alhaidary/Desktop/الحمد لله/check.py", line 23, in get
    if s is 0:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 's' referenced before assignment
```

what should i do???

Comment: don't use `is` to compare `ints`. use `==`

Comment: Why are you fetching all users in the table if you only need information about one specific user (the current one)? And your variable naming scheme has some room for improvement, good names are important.

Comment: Why don't you let sql filter for the user you're checking?

Answer (score 6):

Define `s` before to assign it a value (also, change the test on `s`):

```
user = users.get_current_user()

be = "SELECT * FROM Benutzer ORDER BY date "

c = db.GqlQuery(be)

s=0    # <- init s here

for x in c:
  if x.benutzer == user:
    s=1
    break
  else:
    s=2
if s == 0:    # <- change test on s
  self.redirect('/')
```

Comment: How do I correctly format the code block (with colour, ...) ?

Comment: Don't use `<pre>`, just indent 4 space.  The syntax highlighting is automatic.

Comment: Indent it by 4 spaces, or mark it and use the code button to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Why exactly are you loading all users, then looping through them, just to find one? Use a where clause:

```
be = "SELECT * FROM Benutzer WHERE benutzer=:1"
c = db.GqlQuery(be, user)
user_from_db = c.get()
if user_from_db is not None: # found someone
    dostuff()
else:
    self.redirect('/')
```

Comment: I'd vote you up twice if I could, this wasn't his question but it should be his answer.

Comment: Wooble: Ok, I've never used AppEngine so I didn't know.

Answer (score 2):

You want to set `s` to 0 before the `for` loop starts.  If the query returns zero items, your `for` loop doesn't loop even once, so `s` is undefined.

Also, you should use `if s == 0:` instead of `if s is 0:`.  In CPython, they are both equivalent, but you shouldn't rely on the fact.  See: the documentation for [PyInt_FromLong](http://docs.python.org/c-api/int.html#PyInt_FromLong) and ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/python-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers).

Comment: Why shouldn't he rely on that fact?

Comment: `is` tests that the variables refer to the same object in memory, `==` tests that their values are equal. CPython caches small `int`s (<265 I think) for optimisation, so all references to them point to the same place in memory. This is not true of large `int`s, or guaranteed by the specification.

Comment: @wizard, because it's an implementation detail of one implementation of python. there is jython, pypy, ironpython, unladenswallow... any of those might decide not to cache the small ints. besides the code should **say what you mean**

Comment: I understand what you mean now, I've spent 30 minutes trying to find the docs on "is".

Answer (score 2):

You're using 's' before you assign something to it. Add an 's = 0' in the appropriate location.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that if `c` is an empty list then the code in the `for` loop is never run and `s` never gets set, hence the error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 's' referenced before assignment
```

What the error is telling you that you're referencing - i.e. using - `s` before it has any value - i.e. before a value has been assigned to it.

To fix this you just ensure `s` always is assigned a value:

```
s = 0

for x in c:
    if x.benutzer == user:
        s = 1
        break
    else:
        s = 2
```

Comment: the `else` clause of the `for` loop gets executed if the for loop isn't terminated by a `break`, so this won't work

Comment: @gnibbler - you're right; shouldn't have suggested something I don't use myself.  Have changed to suggested solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the case that `c` is empty the `if` statement in the loop never gets executed

you should set `s=0` before the `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are doing this, but if I understand your code correctly, you have `s=1` when `x.benutzer == user`, and `s=2` otherwise (shouldn't this be `s=0` if you are going to check against 0?).

```
for x in c:
   if x.benutzer == user:
      s=1
      break
   else:
      s=2
if s is 0:
   self.redirect('/')
```

Anyway, here's my solution:

```
if not any(x.benutzer == user for x in c):
   self.redirect('/')
```